# Call Swift ViewController from Objective C ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, navigation, viewcontroller

Trying to navigate into screen A from screen B

Screen A controls Objective-C code (programmatically), screen B - Swift (xib file).

When I trying to run my Swift Class to show BViewController from Objective-C like that:

```
BViewController *addController = [[BViewController alloc] init];
addController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:addController animated:YES completion: nil];
```

faced critical error:

```
BViewController.swift: 18: 12: Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'sensemp.PasscodeLockViewController'
```

some code from BViewController:

```
...

private static var nibName: String { return "BView" }

open class var nibBundle: Bundle {
        return bundleForResource(name: nibName, ofType: "nib")
    }

public init(state: BState, configuration: BConfiguration, animateOnDismiss: Bool = true) {
        ...

        let this = type(of: self)
        super.init(nibName: this.nibName, bundle: this.nibBundle )

        ...
        
    }
...
```

When I manage BViewController from swift directly - all works fine.

What could be the reason for this error? And how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look up that error?

Comment: Yes. initWithNib deprecated in objective-c ?

Comment: It should be `initWithNibName:bundle:`

Comment: I’ve tried - it’s not available! Only init and initWithCoder

Comment: How is `BViewController` defined? If it inherits from `UIViewController` then `initWithNibName:bundle:` definitely exists

Comment: BViewController inherits UIViewController. the addition "@objc" into "open class BViewController: UIViewController" did not helps. Trying to call BViewController like that: "BViewController *coolViewCtrlObj=[[BViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:coolViewCtrlObj  animated:YES];" Faced error "'initWithNibName:bundle:' is unavailable"

Comment: Are you using a Bridging Header? See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift

Comment: Also used bridging header. Added in *.plist file